# Natural numbers equal to the sum of the squares of their four smallest divisors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, diophantine-equations

I was in the process of answering this question when I fell asleep; when I woke up, I found that the question has been closed for being too vague:

[Find all positive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3509645/find-all-positive-integers)

Anyhow, the mathematical problem is as follows:

Given a natural number $n > 0$, let $1$, $a$, $b$, and $c$ be the smallest four divisors of $n$, such that $1 < a < b < c$. Find all possible natural numbers $n$ such that $1^2 + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = n$.

Comment: I thought @DonThousand had solved this in his comments on the closed question: answer $n=130=1^2+2^2+5^2+10^2$.

Comment: @almagest his reasoning for one of the steps in his solution is faulty as I explained in my comments below his, and I would like to have a rigourous proof of his work.

Comment: @MadeleineBirchfield FYI, the other question wasn't actually closed for "being too vague". Instead, the reason mentioned is "needs details or clarity", but I can see why you could think it was due to vagueness. Note this is now the recommended option where previously questions were closed for lacking context. For more info., see the meta post [New recommended close reason for questions that are "missing context"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31147/new-recommended-close-reason-for-questions-that-are-missing-context).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$n$ must be even, because if it were odd the four divisors would be odd and the sum of squares would be even.

The two smallest divisors are $1$ and $2$.  $n$ cannot be a multiple of $4$ because if the fourth divisor is $p$ we have $n=1^2+2^2+4^2+p^2=21+p^2$ and squares $\bmod 4$ are $0,1$ so the right cannot be a multiple of $4$.

If the four smallest divisors were $1,2,p,q$ for $p,q$ prime the sum of squares would be odd, so the four smallest divisors are $1,2,p,2p$ for $p$ an odd prime.

If $n$ has a factor $3$, the four smallest divisors would be $1,2,3,6$ but then $n=50$ and it is not divisible by $3$.

$n=1^2+2^2+p^2+(2p)^2=5(p^2+1)$.  As $n$ has a factor $5$, $p$ must be $5$.  This gives $n=130$ as the only solution.

Comment: Sometimes the best way to solve a problem is to keep it simple and not overthink the problem. Here I was trying to constrain the solution sets for all possible diophantine equations and using elliptic curves and Skolem's p-adic method (granted I was trying to correct Don Thousand's error as it was his solution method, which ended up leading to multiple classes of diophantine equations).

Comment: Ross, do you mean that 'then either $n = 6$ or $n = 30$' instead of 'then $n = 50$' for 'if $n$ has a factor of $3$'?

Comment: No.  I just computed the sum of squares of $1,2,3,6$ and got $50$, which does not have $3$ as a factor.

Comment: If $n$ has a factor of 3, then the four smallest divisors could still be 1, 2, 3, and 5, say $n = 30$ or $n = 150$ or $n = 210$.

Comment: But then the sum of squares is odd.

Comment: Whoops missed that.

Comment: Back to my original point, your statement would be better written as "If $n$ has a factor 3, the four smallest divisors would be 1,2,3,6 but then $n=50$ and 50 is not divisible by 3." for clarity's sake/logical coherence.

Comment: @MadeleineBirchfield:  I have done that.  When you reach a contradiction it is sometimes hard to decide which side to list.  I think this is better.